# Using layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout

Why the button on the middle dissapears? Instead of stretch to fill all the width of their parent? And whereas when I set layout_height = 0dp it doest with height and fills their parent?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: can you draw the pic and upload the image here that how you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the linear layout orientation is vertical, only remaining height will be occupied if the layout_weight is "1", orientation is key here. if you want width to be shared, you might to change the orientation to "horizontal". keep in mind that your children then will be placed horizontally.